# How can I call a function after async.forEachOfSeries completes it's task

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I need to call a function after async.forEachOfSeries completes it's task. I have an Object named `rows`. It contains `postId` and other information. I need to make a request inside the funtion `abc()` to get comments of that particular post and save them in database. If crawling is done then I call `callback()` to make request for the next post in `rows`. When loop is finished, I need to call the function `xyz()`. Here's a sample code:

```
function loopTest(){
    async.forEachOfSeries(rows, function (que, key, callback) {
        function abc(){
            //make request to facebookto get comments and stores in database
        }
        if(!commentCrawlingDone)
        {
            abc();
        }
        else{
            callback();
        }
    });

    xyz();
}
```

Comment: `else{  callback(); } xyz();`?

Comment: You have not provided enough code, or a good explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachOfSeries

You're currently passing two arguments to `.eachOfSeries`; looks like you can pass `xyz` as a third argument.

(`rows` is your first argument, and your anonymous function that takes `(que, key, callback)` is your second argument.)

So, instead of

```
...
  });

  xyz();
```

you would write

```
...
  }, xyz);
```

Comment: Or, since in the docs it also says "Returns: a promise, if a callback is omitted", you could write  ...  }).then(xyz);

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for this. I'm new in Stackoverflow that's why my upvote is not showing up. thanks a lot